# Image relative path not working with Angular

Tags: html, angular, image

I'm trying to display an image stored in my /public/img/"image_file" project's directory system.

```
/home/adrian/Escritorio/proyectos/mean-social-network/frontend/src/app/public/img/beach2.jpg
```

I'm need to display it from the next component HTML file: index.component.html
[image]

Why this relative path is not working?
[image]

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, you should have assets folder in one level with the app folder
and you can write URL in the components and HTML parts like this:

```
<img src="/assets/*.svg">

background-image: url('/assets/*.svg');
```